# Getting access token from Authenticated Referrals

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

Exchanging codes for access tokens from facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php 
is the same as from facebook.com/dialog/oauth ?

I mean, this works just fine on my site: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

But when I try to process code from auth dialog generated by Facebook itself (links from actions) it fails every time with a "100" error code.

Using "client_cred" as "type" I was able to get the app token, which is useless.

The "redirect_uri" are exactly the same.

Best part is that a simple refresh works! Maybe some sync issue?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very sad, but I found a way... kind of:

After trying to get the token (and failing), I hit Facebook oauth AGAIN and this time people wont see the dialog (as it is already authorized) and I get a good code to exchange for a good token and thus, it will not loop, as now I have a $token.

```
 if(empty($token)) {      
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");

        }
```